# Are neighborhood bases always a subset of a basis?

Tags: general-topology

**The definition of basis and neighborhood basis are:**

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, a base of $\tau$ is a subset $\mathfrak{B}$ of $\tau$ such that each open set $A \in \tau$ is union of elements of $\mathfrak{B}$

If $p \in X$, a subset $\mathfrak{B}_p\subseteq U_p=\{U \in \tau | p \in U\}$ of neighborboods of $  p$ is called a neighborhood basis of $ p$ if for each $U \in U_p$ there exist an $V\in \mathfrak{B}_p$ such that $V\subseteq U$

**Additionaly, I have the following proposition in my lectures notes**

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space

(1) If $\mathfrak{B}$ is a basis of $\tau$ and if $p\in X$, the set $\mathfrak{B}_p=\{B \in \mathfrak{B}| p \in B\}$ is a neighborhood basis at $p$.

(2) If for each  $p\in X$ a neighborhood basis at $p $ : $\mathfrak{B}_p$ is defined, the set $\mathfrak{B}=\{B \in \mathfrak{B}_p | p \in X\}$ is a basis of $\tau$

**and the definition of countable basis and countable neighborhood basis**

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. If $\tau$ admits a basis whose cardinality is countable, $\tau$ is said to have a countable basis

If  each $p \in X$ admits a countably-infinite neighborhood basis, $\tau$ is said to have a countably-infinite neighborhood basis

In those cases $(X, \tau)$ is called a  countable-basis topological space or countable-neighborhood-basis topological space respectively.

*The term countable includes finite sets: a set is countable if it is finite or countably-infinite.

**Then they say that** by the second statement (2) of  the initial proposition, countable basis implies countable neighborhood basis(that is if $\mathfrak{B}$is countable, then $\mathfrak{B}_p$ is countable), but the converse is not true. ....(3)

A couple of related questions

1. **Are neighborhood bases always a subset of a basis as stated in (1)** : $\mathfrak{B}_p=\{B \in \mathfrak{B}| p \in B\}$ ?, or this is just one possibility?
2. **I attempt to give an explanation of (3):**

Since by (1)(they used (2), but I do not agree, I Think I need (1)), $\mathfrak{B}_p \subseteq \mathfrak{B}$, $\mathfrak{B}$ is countable by hypothesis  and a subset of a countable set is countable, it follows that  $\mathfrak{B}_p $ is countable.
The converse is not true, because we could have an uncountable number of points in X, for which the union of countable neighbordhood bases might not be countable

**Is this explanation correct?**, as you see it depends heavily on the definition of  $\mathfrak{B}_p$ as a subset of $\mathfrak{B}$, so it wouldn't be general if a neighborhood basis could be defined without taking the elements from a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$, and $p\in X$, the set $\mathscr{B}_p=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:p\in B\}$ is always a nbhd base at $p$. However, it is entirely possible to have a base $\mathscr{B}$ for $\tau$ and a nbhd base $\mathscr{B}_p$ at $p$ such that $\mathscr{B}_p\cap\mathscr{B}=\varnothing$. For instance, let $X=\Bbb R$, and let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. Let

$$\mathscr{B}=\{(p,q):p,q\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<q\}\;,$$

the set of open intervals with rational endpoints; $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $\tau$. Let

$$\mathscr{B}_0=\{(-x,x):0<x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\}\;,$$

the set of symmetric open intervals around $0$ with **irrational** endpoints. Clearly $\mathscr{B}_0\cap\mathscr{B}=\varnothing$, but $\mathscr{B}_0$ is nevertheless a nbhd base at $0$.

The best way to explain (3) is to give an actual example showing that it is possible to have a countable nbhd base at each point but no countable base for the whole topology. Probably the simplest example is to let $X$ be an uncountable set and $\tau=\wp(X)$ the discrete topology on $X$. For each $x\in X$ the collection $\big\{\{x\}\big\}$ is a nbhd base at $x$, and it’s certainly countable! However, any base for $\tau$ must include every one of the singleton sets $\{x\}$ for $x\in X$ and must therefore be uncountable.

Comment: So, you are explaining (3) with a concrete example of what I said : that we could have an uncountable number of points in X, for which the union of countable neighbordhood bases might not be countable. If you were asking this on a exam, does it stand on its own without the example?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: No: to show that the converse is not in general true, you must provide an actual counterexample to it.

Comment: In (3), the initial part, which you didn't mention anything about  why countable basis implies countable neighborhood basis, is it correct to use (2) as they are doing?. Because I think it should be explained using (1) and not (2), what do you think? (I edited that part after you read it I presume)

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: Yes, that conclusion depends on the first assertion, not the second: you need the fact that every base for a topology contains a nbhd base at each point of the space.

Comment: Great, so you agree the subset-of-a-countable-set-is-countable argument correctly explains it? but  I have the feeling anyway that the corrected explanation relays on the fact of the nbhd basis being a subset of the basis  but you showed is not necessarily true.Then, something must be missing because this is an argument for a particular case, isn't it?. What would the general argument be?

Comment: ...at least somehow the general case could be reconduced to the particular one always

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: The general argument is simply that if $X$ has a countable base $\mathscr{B}$, then for each $p\in X$ the family $\mathscr{B}_p=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:p\in B\}$ is a nbhd base at $p$, and since $\mathscr{B}_p$ is a subset of the countable set $\mathscr{B}$, it must also be countable. $X$ may also have uncountable bases, but we don’t care about them for this result.